# Подсказать по публикации ASP.NET Core приложении

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, хостинг, развертывание

Коллеги, возник небольшой вопрос насчет публикации ASP.NET Core приложения.
У меня в планах сделать не сложный сайт на .NET. Пока в стадии планирования. В ходе обдумывания появилось несколько вопросов, на которые не смог найти нормального ответа

1. Знаю, что на рускоязычном рынке не так много хостингов на Windows Server. Если я буду создавать сайт через Core, то смогу ли я публиковать его через сервер с *nix ОС? Если да, то трудаёмкая ли это задача?
2. Есль ли вариант публикации сайта через docker-образ? Если да, где можно найти инструкцию?(сразу скажу, что с docer не работал, но хотел бы попробовать, и, если вопрос поставлен не корректно или не правильно, то не обессудьте)
3. Возможно ли что то похожее сделать через сервера Azure? Тяжело ли это сделать?
4. Зависит ли от хостинга поддержка PWA(имеется в ввиду, что мое приложение уже реализует PWA)?

P.S. Понимаю, что скорее всего вопрос не самый уместный для этой платформы, но возможно кто то сталкивался)

Comment: По-моему, в [официальной документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/) все предельно ясно расписано как развертывать .NET Core приложение на различных платформах.

Comment: 1. Да. 2. Да. 3. Да. Вряд ли. 4. Нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Да, Asp.net Core - это кроссплатформенный фреймворк, и поддерживает развертывание на Linux и MacOS [инструкция от Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
2. По поводу докера также он поддерживается [по докеру](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
3. Azure - это в некотором роде "родная" платформа и там тоже сложностей возникнуть не должно [Азур](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
4. C PWA также вроде все норм, можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/labs/insiderdevtour2018/pwa/)

Хотя ссылки указаны для версии 2.2 но там в плане деплоя вроде как критических изменений нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот похожее решение [https://deploy-f.com](https://deploy-f.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow_926176&utm_medium=organic).
Нужно просто собрать билд, положить в архив и залить, никаких мучений с vps.
Вот тут https://youtu.be/d8A-l_NMpYQ?t=833 расказывается как залить и запустить .net core приоложение через deploy-f

2. Есть поддержка Docker. Можно запускать контейнеры как из приватных репозиториев так и с публичных. Есть поддержка сборки Dockerfile, нужно просто закинуть файл докера в корень с исходным кодом, запаковать архив и залить. Можно обойтись локальной сборкой приложения и отправить в deploy-f, тоже запустится.
3. По сравнению с Azure, deploy-f намного проще.
4. PWA это решение реализуемое вами, от хостинга тут мало что зависит.